# Do threads of a process share the same register set or only the current running thread has the whole register set dedicated to it

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

A process always has the register set dedicated to it .
Does the same happen  to threads of a process . More specifically let the register set contain 10 registers . Now suppose I run a process having two threads .
Does the first thread share the register set with the second one(like first thread having 5 registers and second having 5) or does it have exclusive access to the entire register set .

Comment: please explain in detail

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down.  I've just begun learning how to use SIMD registers and this all of the sudden seems like something that definitely matters to know for sure.  I voted this question up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads are oblivious to those things. 
During a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), the state of cpu registers are saved and restored the same way whether or not the threads of execution are within the same process or different processes.

> A process always has the register set dedicated to it

False. It is the same registers for all processes. The process just think it is dedicated to itself.

> Does the thread have exclusive access to the entire register set

Yes